# Magento 1.9.2.4 Admin Permission Role and Users Issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, user-roles

In magento , I can create a sub-admin giving access to limited resources. But if I allow any sub-admin to create new sub-admin role and user then he is allowed to give all the access to the new sub-admin even which are not available to him..
(I mean all the module are available to him in Role Resources Tree Under add New Role, even which are not assigned to him)

For example: If sub admin is not having access to reports,Order he can not allow the reports,Order access to the other user he is creating from his access.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving User & Role access to sub-admin, then he/she can create new user as well as role. Magento doesn't check it's own access level. According to your requirement, you have to override admin Permission module.

Create custom extension to overcome from this issue or try any ready extension for it.